# Np array en arrreglo for

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Estoy realizando una operación el cual deseo que se guarden diferentes datos en ese array, pero al momento de operar solo me esta guardando el primer valor. Probe declarando rm=[] y después en  el el ciclo for voy agregando los datos pero me sale Error de que no puedo operar una lista con float.

Esta es la linea que me genera el problema **rm = np.append(rm,r)**

Este es el código

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import numpy as np


root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Piston')
root.geometry('450x210')


rho=DoubleVar()
c=DoubleVar()
uo=DoubleVar()
a=DoubleVar()
fr=DoubleVar()


def calcularpresion():
      rho1=rho.get()
      c1=c.get()
      uo1=uo.get()
      a1=a.get()
      fr1=fr.get()
      fs = np.arange(20,20000,math.log(10))
      ks= (2 * math.pi * fs)/c1
      lamda=c1/fr1
      r=a1*((a1/lamda)-((1/4)*(lamda/a1))) 
      p=2*rho1*c1*uo1*(np.sin((1/4)*ks*r*((a1/r)**2)))
      graficar(fs,p)

def calcularr():
      rm=np.array([])
      rho1=rho.get()
      c1=c.get()
      uo1=uo.get()
      a1=a.get()
      fr1=fr.get()
      lamda=c1/fr1
      for i in range(10):
            i=i+1
            r=(a1*(((1/i)*(a1/lamda))-((i/4)*(lamda/a1))))
            rm = np.append(rm,r)
      fs = np.array([63, 125, 250, 500, 1000, 2000, 4000, 8000, 16000, 20000])
      ks= (2 * math.pi * fs)/c1
      p=2*rho1*c1*uo1*(np.sin((1/4)*ks*r*((a1/rm)**2)))
      plt.plot(r,p)
      plt.xlabel('R')
      plt.ylabel('Presión')
      plt.show()      

def graficar(x,y):
      plt.plot(x,y,'b', label='Presión del Piston')
      plt.grid(True)
      plt.xlabel('Frecuencia (Hz)')
      plt.ylabel('Presión')
      plt.xscale('log') 
      plt.show()

label=tk.Label(root, text=' Piston')
label.grid(row=1, column=1)
label2=tk.Label(root, text=' Densidad de aire')
label2.grid(row=2, column=1)
label3=tk.Label(root, text=' Velocidad del sonido')
label3.grid(row=3, column=1)
label4=tk.Label(root, text=' Velocidad volumetrica')
label4.grid(row=4, column=1)
label5=tk.Label(root, text=' Radio del Piston')
label5.grid(row=5, column=1)
label6=tk.Label(root, text=' Frecuencia de resonancia')
label6.grid(row=6, column=1)

entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=rho)
entry.grid(row=2, column=2)
entry2 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=c)
entry2.grid(row=3, column=2)
entry3 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=uo)
entry3.grid(row=4, column=2)
entry4 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=a)
entry4.grid(row=5, column=2)
entry5 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=fr)
entry5.grid(row=6, column=2)

button= tk.Button(text='Graficar Presion',command=calcularpresion)
button.grid(row=7, column=2)

button2=tk.Button(text='Graficar R',command=calcularr).grid(row=9, column=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Estoy realizando una operación el cual deseo que se guarden diferentes datos en ese array, pero al momento de operar solo me esta guardando el primer valor. Probe declarando rm=[] y después en  el el ciclo for voy agregando los datos pero me sale Error de que no puedo operar una lista con float.

Esta es la linea que me genera el problema **rm = np.append(rm,r)**

Gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En vez de un ineficiente `for` con `numpy.append`, que crea un nuevo array en cada iteración (en estos casos mejor usar una lista) puedes vectorizar la operación:

```
rm = np.arange(1, 11)
rm = (a1 * (((1 / rm) * (a1 / lamda)) - ((rm / 4) * (lamda / a1))))
```

El código completo sería:

```
def calcularr():
    rho1 = rho.get()
    c1 = c.get()
    uo1 = uo.get()
    a1 = a.get()
    fr1 = fr.get()
    lamda = c1 / fr1

    rm = np.arange(1, 11)
    rm = (a1 * (((1 / rm) * (a1 / lamda)) - ((rm / 4) * (lamda / a1))))

    fs = np.array([63, 125, 250, 500, 1000, 2000, 4000, 8000, 16000, 20000])
    ks = (2 * math.pi * fs) / c1
    p = 2 * rho1 * c1 * uo1 * (np.sin((1 / 4) * ks * rm[-1] * ((a1 / rm) ** 2)))
    plt.plot(rm, p)
    plt.xlabel('R')
    plt.ylabel('Presión')
    plt.show()
```

En tu código:

```
p=2*rho1*c1*uo1*(np.sin((1/4)*ks*r*((a1/rm)**2)))
                                 ^
                                 ^
```

`r` es el último elemento agregado al array calculado en el `for`, por lo que lo cambio por `r[-1]`.

Por último, no sería `plt.plot(r, p)`, sino `plt.plot(rm, p)`.

Comment: Vale, entonces no es necesario volver a hacer un ciclo for para este tipo de casos con numpy. Gracias